# Not able to add time in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have been learning SQL,and I was trying out this command:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'HH:MM:SS'),TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+INTERVAL '15' MINUTE,'HH:MM:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

However the output I am getting is [image]

I even tried out this command:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE,'HH:MM:SS'),TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+15/1440,'HH:MM:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Even then I am getting this output:
[image]

Can anyone explain why am I not getting the second time as 15 minutes ahead of the current system date?

PS: I am using Oracle LiveSQL.

Comment: confused with wrong formatting, just replace `MM`(for months) with `MI` :)

Comment: Yes it helped...thanks a lot!

Comment: `HH` is for 12-hour format and should be used with `AM` format element

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Barbaros Özhan in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076035/not-able-to-add-time-in-sql#comment125644214_71076035)

The `MM` [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-4EF054FF-9996-4637-8476-136FC7A8246D) is for months. You want the `MI` format model for minutes.

Additionally, the `HH`format model is an abbreviation for `HH12` and will show the hours in a 12-hour clock. You want `HH24` to use a 24-hour clock.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI:SS') AS now,
       TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+INTERVAL '15' MINUTE,'HH24:MI:SS') AS now_plus_15
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NOW | NOW_PLUS_15 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 12:38:13 | 12:53:13 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10251a807dfd16709ed1f22292d55783)*